# Improving Window function performance

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have inherited some code that produces many new columns in terms of window functions.

Sadly all of the Window functions partition on a different column. In some cases there is no partitionBy clause at all which further degrades performance.

1. Would it be more effective to implements each Window as a groupBy instead (where possible) to generate the new column and join each new column in based on the groupBy keys. The number of partitions is rather small so the actual joins themselves would be cheap and could be broadcasted.
2. Is there any way to optimise a Winsow function with no partitioning? I have read that a dummy partition key , e.g lit(0) can be used but surely this still results in the ordering being performed in a single partition?

Cheers

Terry

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that you can get significant performance gains using agg and optionally groupBy in certain scenarios.

In my case I had multiple rank over window functions.

I created a separate DataFrames that calculated min for the same partitions and orderings.

Each of these DataFrames returned a single row (where the partitionBy clause in the window was not defined) or a handful of rows where the partitionBy clause was specified.

Obviously this comes with an overhead but calculating these min values in a few DataFrames  and performing the broadcast joins to add the relevant columns was a lot cheaper than using Window functions.

Obviously this approach will only work in certain scenarios - if you are using something like lag then you are probably stuck with Window functions...